# What force could act on an unconstrained rotating disc that would change its point of rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If a disc were rotating without friction or gravity could a force be applied for a time that would cause the disc for a time to rotate around a point other than the center of mass? If so how would the inertia of the more massive side of the new point of rotation affect the motion of the disc?

Comment: What's the difference between "forces acting on a disc" and a "constrained disc"?

Comment: Perhaps "constrained" is not the correct word. A rotating disc in space without an axle, friction or gravity is the intended meaning.

Comment: Those things are just ways of placing forces on the disc.  So if they are not present, how would you introduce a "force applied for a time", and why would that force be any different than one from an axle?

Comment: Much simpler than that. An example is a spaceship with the forces introduced by thrusters. It would not be different from an axle. BowlOfRed your answer is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

During the time the force is applied, yes any particular axis could be maintained.  After the force is removed, no.  In a frame where the center of mass is at rest, the only rotation will be about the center of mass.

Pop a nail into your disc away from the center.  Fix the nail and spin the disc.  The disc is now rotating about a point that is not the center of mass, and this is due to forces applied to it from the nail.